# Hide arObject from sceneform scene

Tags: kotlin, arcore, sceneform

I am new in ArCore and Sceneform. I have an arObject in arSceneView and I want to hide it from the scene (for few seconds). I don't want to detach() the anchor from the scene but just hide it and then show it again after few seconds.

I have tried to change the parameters of .sfa file but it didn't work

```
parameters: [{
               baseColor: "ARObject",
            },
            {
               baseColorTint: [
                  0.64000000000000001,
                  0.64000000000000001,
                  0.64000000000000001,
                  0.5,
               ],
            },
            {
               metallic: 1,
            },
            {
               roughness: 1,
            },
            {
               opacity: 0.1,
            },
         ],
```

or is there any other way that I am missing

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way may be to simply delete the renderable from the anchor and then re-add it.

You do not meed to delete the anchor itself.

Comment: thanks for the reply yes I have tried that but I have a situation where I have multiple arObjects which I wanted to hide do you have any recommendation for that ?

Comment: There is not actually a class called arObject (AFAIK) but I think you mean renderables - if you store all the renderables in your scene in some sort of collection, along with info about the anchor they are  attached to,, you should be able to iterate though them and delete and then iterate again and re-add them.